# Insert a dates in list of dates in flask_sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

With flask_sqlalchemy and a PostgreSQL database, I'm trying to add a date to a date list. My column is set as "timestamp with timezone[]" with a default value of an empty list

it's defined like this ->

`last_login = db.Column(ARRAY(DateTime(timezone=True)), default=[])`

When I'm login I add this in my code ->

`admin.last_login.extend([datetime.now(dt.timezone.utc)])    db.session.commit()`

The result is still an empty list, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can we please get a [mcve]?

Comment: It has been a while since I used SQLAlchemy, from what I see you extending the list but not actually updating the table. Not sure how that works, but I assume there needs to be an `update()` in there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Adrian is correct. You need to add the object to the transaction for it to update.
You should be able to do this, assuming that `admin` is a SQLAlchemy model:

```py
admin.last_login.extend([datetime.now(dt.timezone.utc)])
db.session.add(admin)
db.session.commit()
```

Without the `db.session.add(admin)`, the session isn't being modified and so the call to `db.session.commit()` is committing an empty transaction.

Comment: Even with this line, I had nothing registered in the DB. I finally created a dedicated table for last_login to bypass this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I finally created a dedicated table for last_login to bypass this issue.

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76256847/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).